# Opening local files in Webkit .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, webkit, webkit.net

A simple WebKitBrowser1.Navigate(localfilehere) doesn't work for some reason.

I tried adding "file://" to the URL but that didn't work either.

This seems ridiculous but is this functionality really not present?

Answer (score 5):

Its look like you put wrong url. You can check it by

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString
```

One of the reasons - you put the string with national symbols.

In this case the answers before do not resolve you problem, because you also should encode url.

You can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` for it and then apply a solution described 
before by [X Enterprises](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548040/x-enterprises) (but you should not replace spaces - it would be already done by encoding) .

But the easiest way to get correct url is

```
string url = new Uri(pathToFile, UriKind.Absolute).AbsoluteUri;
```

Answer (score 3):

"file://" is the correct protocol. To get to a file say in... "c:\temp\test.html" you can try something like:

"file://c/temp/test.html"

Note the forward slash and the absence of the colon after the drive letter.

Answer (score 2):

WebKit.Net 0.5 `Navigate()` function takes string as its parameter(local/web files). For local file for e.g: `c:\xxx\yyy zzz.htm` can be passed to Navigate Function as follows:-

```
dim sFile As String = "c:\xxx\yyy zzz.htm"
Dim url as new Uri(sFile, UriKind.Absolute)

'Now pass the file's required formatted absolute path
WebKitBrowser1.Navigate(url.AbsoluteUri)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to your problem:

1.) Make sure the path begins with "file:///"
2.) Make sure you use the file's full path
3.) Make sure all backslashes are changed to forward slashes
4.) Make sure you replace all spaces, " ", with "%20"
5.) Make sure the file ends in ".html"

So, a file here:
"C:\Program Files\test.html"
would need to become:
"file:///C:/Program%20Files/test.html"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sample HTML page.
Upload into my resources.

Use this code:
WebKitBrowser1.document.write(my.resources.page.html)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose index.html is in bin/debug folder then

Use "file:///"+Environment.CurrentDirectory.Replace(@"\",@"/")+"/index.html"

Suppose index.html is in bin/debug and created folder like www then

Use  "file:///"+Environment.CurrentDirectory.Replace(@"\",@"/")+"/www/index.html"

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome you can open a local file by entering file:/// followed by the complet path of the file, so it is possible taht you need to use the same operator on Webkit.

Comment: Are you changing all of the back slashes in the file name to forward slashed, too? file:///C:/Folder/SubFolder/Test.html

Comment: I am having the same problem, I am changing slashes. I am able to use webkitBrowser.Navigate to display some html file, but then I am not able to load javascript referenced from this html. So I am not able to include jquery for instance.