# openwebkitsharp read/write protected memory

Tags: css, backbone.js, webkit.net

I am trying to integrate webkit.net into my project. I started off with **OpenWebkitSharp 3.0** because it supports latest HTML5/CSS3 but I am always experiencing crash from clicking the page and even on load sometimes. The error I get is below:

**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

I can't fathom the issue as it happens randomly just by navigating through the page. From various articles I read online that error is from Webkit.dll and I was advised to wait for the release of more stable version.

After multiple days of trials, I found another version **[webkitdotnet-develop](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet)** which seems to be more stable but it doesn't support webfonts(.ttf/woff/svg) with Backbone.js framework. The webfonts worked fine with a simple html file but not with the backbone.js eventhough I was able to load same file using google/firefox browsers with no problem. I guess something in backbone.js is breaking the @font-face style from displaying in the WebkitBrowser.

Could someone help with any of the two issues? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I am always experiencing crash from clicking the page and even on load sometimes.

The underlying DOM interfaces for events are not fully implemented, which leads to a null reference

> The webfonts worked fine with a simple html file but not with the backbone.js

The Backbone view creates IDs and class names dynamically, so find the bindings in the `render` and create matching selectors for fonts:

```
  <style>
  .fonty { 
         font: 14px/1.4em "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
         color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  }
  </style>

  <script>
  render: function() {
  this.$el.toggleClass('fonty', this.model.get('done'));
  }
  </script>
```

**References**

- [Opening local files in Webkit .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606901/1113772)
- [WebkitdotNet Github Repo](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet)
- [IDOMHTMLInputElement.Click()](http://sourceforge.net/p/webkitdotnet/discussion/939856/thread/148b1f5c/?limit=250#a5d5)
- [WebkitdotNet: 0.5 Released](http://sourceforge.net/p/webkitdotnet/news/2010/08/05-released--source-now-on-github/)
- [WebkitdotNet: 0.4 Released](http://sourceforge.net/p/webkitdotnet/news/2010/03/04-released/)
- [Backbone Example: todos](http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html)